# Access to pointer passed to realloc

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    int *p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *q = (int *)realloc(p,sizeof(int));
    *p = 3;
    *q = 9;
    if (p == q)
        printf("%d %d", *p, *q);

}
```

when i run this it print 9 9 in GCC. 
Can someone explain the behavior of this code?

Comment: Your `realloc()` call is unlikely to change the pointer `p`, so the call is equivalent to `q = p`.

Comment: What do you expect? `9` is a valid integer, so it can be the result.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi No. Successful `realloc()` always invalidates the original pointer.

Comment: Using a pointer after a successful `realloc()` on it is *undefined behavior*, end of story.

Comment: ..and please don't ask for UB to be explained further:(

Comment: The code isn't even valid C++ (removed that tag) and in C, it's a deprecated feature to leave out the return type of a function. This should be `int main(void)`!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## What does the standard say?

Going strictly by the standard, your program exhibits undefined behavior (C standard, 7.22.3.5):

> The `realloc` function **deallocates the old object** pointed to by `ptr` and returns a pointer to **a new object** that has the size specified by `size`. The contents of the new object shall be the same as that of the old object prior to deallocation, up to the lesser of the new and old sizes. Any bytes in the new object beyond the size of the old object have indeterminate values.

The two objects involved in `realloc` are not the same - the new one is allocated, and you know its contents are the same as the old one, and the old one is destroyed. Your dereference of `p` is access to an object outside its lifetime, which is undefined.

## What (probably) happens in practice here?

[`realloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) *can* move the memory area if necessary, but does not *have to* move the memory area.

In this situation, both allocations are of the same size (`sizeof(int)`). `realloc` very likely realizes this and doesn't move the memory area at all.

As a result, `p == q`.

*PS: "probably" because the behavior is undefined. Your compiler might just analyze the `realloc` code path and notice that the only legal way the program can work is if `realloc` doesn't move the pointer, and optimizes to `q = p` instead. You'd need to investigate the assembly generated to really find out.*

Comment: Adjusted the answer to include the UB

Comment: You should probably mention paragraph 4, *Returns*, which states that the returned pointer might have the same value of the passed pointer.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi that's what I refer to when I say "_can_ move the memory area, but does not _have to_"

Comment: Thanks Treeston for your explanation